# Hide LabVIEW icon of executable from the taskbar

Tags: executable, labview, taskbar

I am working on a project on which I call some LabVIEW programs which are executables. I don't want to see what happens on these one, so I set the transparency of the front panel at 100%. Like this, I don't see the labVIEW program. After the execution, LabVIEW is quitting automatically.

However, when LabVIEW is running, I have the icon of labVIEW in the taskbar of windows.

Do you know how to hide it? I already tried to add `HideRootWindow=True` on the .ini file but it is not working.

Comment: Again, you can [find an answer on google](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Show-Hide-icon-of-my-application-in-the-Window-taskbar-at-run/td-p/3593854) and test it.

Comment: If I come here, it is because I already search quickly on google and don't find easy solution. I am not the type of asking questions without a minimum of research before. It is just sometimes I have not the key words in english to search correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this solution](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Show-Hide-icon-of-my-application-in-the-Window-taskbar-at-run/td-p/3593854) by Alexander Sobolev:

```
For application.exe in file application.ini add row HideRootWindow=True
When you activate VI, set VI-> Property node Front Panel window.Minimizable = True, show window (invoke node VI.Open, window state = standard).
When hiding, you need to track that, set Minimizable = False
Taskbar icon will appear and disappear with window
```

He also provides the code (which should be "draggable" to labview to run):

[image]

Comment: I only add first part (with setting False FP.Minizable), and it is working. Very very nice ! Thank you